# Load Div created by script after page loaded.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I load a div after a page has been loaded and created by a script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').append('<div class="div_new" alt="hi">Hello World</div>');
});
$('.button').click(function(){
   alt_value = $('.div_new').attr('alt');
   alert(alt_value);
});
```

I'm trying to load a div created by a script.

Comment: Put your `.button` handler inside the DOM ready statement after the `.append`

Comment: Is the `$(".button").click` called before `.button` is loaded in the DOM?

Comment: Or you can attach the click handler somewhere at the bottom of the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click handler needs to go inside the DOM ready handler. Without doing this, you will be trying to attach the `click()` to an element which doesn't yet exist. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div class="div_new" alt="hi">Hello World</div>');

    $('.button').click(function(){
        alt_value = $('.div_new').attr('alt');
        alert(alt_value);
    });
});
```